# how to upgrade libc6 on debian 7.1?

Tags: debian

When trying to install pagespeed on my debian 7.1

```
Unpacking mod-pagespeed-stable (from mod-pagespeed-stable_current_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mod-pagespeed-stable:
 mod-pagespeed-stable depends on libc6 (>= 2.14); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.13-38+deb7u11.

dpkg: error processing mod-pagespeed-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

How to fix that ? (I guess I need to upgrade libc6, but no idea how)

Answer (score 0):

I would say Debian 7 is just too old for pagespeed, however, you could attempt to [build pagespeed from source](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_mod_pagespeed_from_source#checkout) targeting your current version of `libc`.

You will find that the version of `gcc` shipped with Debian 7 is also unsupported. You will need to build a modern `gcc` as well. But this not as destructive as replacing `libc6`.

Whether this is an acceptable solution for you, given the operational overhead, is really up to you. I haven't gone though the entire process to check if it's actually possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and instead of trying to manually build pagespeed or updating libc6 only (without updating all of Debian), I went another route - downloading and installing a version of mod_pagespeed that didn't require libc 2.14 (that turned out to be mod_pagespeed release **1.9.32.14** .

That seemed safer on my somewhat temperamental web server. Keep in mind that this way isn't safe for sites delivering HTTPS pages! (but mine wasn't). The whole solution is broken down here: [mod_pagespeed : install earlier version compatible with libc6 2.13 (Debian Wheezy)](https://serverfault.com/questions/796090/mod-pagespeed-install-earlier-version-compatible-with-libc6-2-13-debian-wheez)

Answer (score -2):

You have three options:

1. Download, compile and install libc6 from the source code. That will work but might mess with your system.
2. Download the [binary package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libc6) directly from a [Debian mirror](https://packages.debian.org/) and install it with *dpkg*. Much better option, but you will need to upgrade it manually in the future.
3. Upgrade your /etc/apt/source.list to Debian Jessie and upgrade libc6 and it's dependencies. That's what I would do.

Comment: Replacing `libc6` by recompiling just that package, or updating just that package is a recipe for disaster. Upgrading the entire operating system although a bit of an overkill solution, might be better.

Comment: @dawud most of the cases that's not an option.

Comment: Well, that's what you listed as option #3 anyway.

Comment: @dawud that's why I didn't understand why you down voted my answer.

Comment: Because of #1 and #2. But don't take it too seriously, it's just internet points. The mere fact of providing an answer is a positive thing, and I would like to encourage you to continue to do so. I just happen to think it's not a very good answer.