# mod_pagespeed : install earlier version compatible with libc6 2.13 (Debian Wheezy)

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, web-server, mod-pagespeed

Might be a stupid question, but how can I get an **_amd64.deb** package version of a **mod_pagespeed** release prior to the current stable/beta versions - i.e. release **1.11.33.0-beta** - https://github.com/pagespeed/mod_pagespeed/tree/1.11.33.0

I need to install mod_pagespeed on my Debian Wheezy server and the current version doesn't support it (libc6 version dependency is now 2.14 and Wheezy has 2.13). Building mod_pagespeed from source or somehow updating libc6 wouldn't be a great option on this important production web server.

I'd love to simply grab and dpkg the latest version that didn't yet require glibc >= 2.14 and would dpkg on Debian Wheezy 7.0 without throwing a dependency error like:

```
sudo dpkg -i mod-pagespeed-stable_current_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package mod-pagespeed-stable.
(Reading database ... 40509 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mod-pagespeed-stable (from mod-pagespeed-stable_current_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mod-pagespeed-stable:
mod-pagespeed-stable depends on libc6 (>= 2.14); however:
Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.13-38+deb7u7.
```

The release notes say the last version that supported this setup is just a couple of releases back - the glibc 2.14 requirement is in place as of v 1.11.33.1-stable in May 2016, so 1.11.33.0-beta should do the trick.

Is there an archive of the older .deb packages out there somewhere? Or a way to reference the version in the URL structure when using wget - i.e. https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/linux/direct/mod-pagespeed-**????**_amd64.deb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[[ IMPORTANT UPDATE: If you're serving secure HTTPS pages on your server (we are not), the below won't be an acceptable solution for you due to a *High Severity* security issue that was resolved in `mod_pagespeed` release `1.11.33.2` , but if you're sticking with HTTP, it will work just fine. - read more on this [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mod-pagespeed-discuss/9u1IbkPhfmA) and at developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/release_notes#release_1.11.33.2-beta ]]**

I dug around and came up with a solution:

It turns out there's a mod_pagespeed amd64 deb package archive at **pkgs.org** :

https://pkgs.org/debian-ubuntu/google-mod_pagespeed-amd64/

Instead of `1.11.33.0-beta` which was available and in theory should have worked, I had to go back to `1.9.32.14` because anything newer still threw this error during `dpkg`:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mod-pagespeed-beta:
mod-pagespeed-beta depends on libc6 (>= 2.14); however:
Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.13-38+deb7u7.
```

So by trial and error, eventually I ran this and it worked :)

```
sudo wget "http://dl.google.com/linux/mod-pagespeed/deb/pool/main/m/mod-pagespeed-stable/mod-pagespeed-stable_1.9.32.14-r0_amd64.deb"
sudo dpkg -i mod-pagespeed-stable_1.9.32.14-r0_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**I now have mod_pagespeed running on Debian Wheezy. I know it's a deprecated version, but still ...**

Comment: there's also this thread on the Google forums - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mod-pagespeed-discuss/9u1IbkPhfmA